# Why is the constraint when maximizing entropy on energy rather than momentum?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, momentum, entropy

State in classical mechanics is specified by the position and the momentum.  Yet, in statistical mechanics, the usual approach is to maximize the entropy of a system subject to an energy constraint.  This gives a probability distribution of the energies, and then other quantities such as velocities can be calculated as a function of energy.

Since momentum is conserved, why not maximize the entropy subject to a momentum constraint rather than energy constraint?

Comment: Typically the energy  in the 'constraint' *includes* a kinetic component...

Comment: The title should say *momentum* rather than ~temperature~

Comment: But the momentum appears in the energy... Perhaps you should spell out a specific derivation and we can use that as an example to clarify.

Comment: Yes, the momentum is conserved, but if it is not equal to zero, it means that the system moves as a whole relative to the external observer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, every conservation law is taken into account when maximizing entropy.

For example, consider an ideal gas in a box that's flying at nearly the speed of light, where the gas has some low temperature $T$ in the frame of the box. In our original frame, the maximum entropy configuration consistent with energy conservation has the ideal gas particles moving at speed about $c$ with respect to each other, and hence at some enormous temperature. But this isn't what happens because it violates momentum conservation; instead the gas just remains at temperature $T$.

It's typically easy to ignore linear and angular momentum because we can just transform into a frame where they're zero. In the context of early-universe cosmology, there are other conservation laws, such as the conservation of charge or baryon number, that must be taken into account.