# Statistical mechanics of a gas in a rotating cylinder

Tags: statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian, ideal-gas, partition-function

The theoretical premises that allow us to study the statistical mechanics of a substance in a rotating equilibrium are not completely clear to me. For example, consider a gas ($N$ non-interacting particles of mass $m$) in a rotating cylinder of radius $R$ aligned with the z-axis. The gas is subject to the gravitational potential along the z-axis and the cylinder is rotating with angular velocity $\omega$.

Probably, we have to find a transformation of coordinates and momenta to describe the particles that follow, on average, the rotating cylinder when the system reaches equilibrium so that the Hamiltonian reads:

\begin{equation}
H = \frac{1}{2m}\biggr[(p_x + m\omega y)^2 + (p_y - m\omega x)^2 + p_z^2 \biggr] + mgz -\frac{1}{2} m{\omega}^2r^2
\end{equation}

where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I think it's possible to write this on the basis of "intuition" (we just remove the velocity of the rotating container from the momenta in the kinetic part of $H$). However, I am not sure how to rigorously justify the above result. At first, I thought to use a [canonical transformation of the second type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) to get the Hamiltonian in a rotating frame.

Moreover, even admitting that I find the correct Hamiltonian in the rotating frame, what is the physical assumption I should make in order to get the correct partition function for the rotating gas? Stated in other terms, which is the theoretical foundation needed to extend statistical mechanics to substances that are in equilibrium but rotating? Can we still use $\exp(-\beta H)$, where $H$ is an opportune Hamiltonian?

**Note:** According to my intuition, particles in the gas should behave like free particles but subject to the potential $-\frac{m{\omega}^2r^2}{2}$, the "potential" for the [centrifugal apparent force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force). Are there other effects due to the Coriolis force?

Comment: Every conservation law or conserved "charge" is taken into account when maximizing entropy. However, linear and angular momentum conservation is typically ignored by considering the frame where they're zero, e.g. [Why is the constraint when maximizing entropy on energy rather than momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385270/226902) Also: [Statistical mechanics of rotating bodies](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/Leggett/courses/fa2006/Lecture14.pdf) by A.J. Leggett or [Statistical Mechanics of Rotating Buckets](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.100.481) by Blatt et al.